# HP Pavilion g7 sound not loud enough in elementary OS

Tags: release-loki, sound, laptop, hp

In **elementary OS** (both **Freya** and **Loki**) my laptop's sound is quiet , sometimes distorted and any volume level below 50 % can hardly be heard (100 % is also not loud enough).

In **Windows 10** (with sound drivers) the speakers are much more powerful and louder and can be heard even at 10 % volume.

What should I do to make the speakers louder on **elementary OS**.

My laptop is a **HP Pavilion g7 2269wm**

Comment: what sound card do you have? have you looked for manufacturer drivers for it?

Comment: Intel HD Audio sound card

Comment: I would try to see if this is an elementary-specific issue, an ubuntu-specific, or a linux-specific one, by testing also with other linuxes from live usb and such - then you can try and post this on askubuntu or U&L

Comment: Its the same on Ubuntu 16.04 (elementary is based on it)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the sound is distorted and the great difference to what happens in Windows may indicate a driver or codec problem.

To boost sound above 100%: System Settings - Sounds: "Allow louder than 100%"

[image]

Installing `pavucontrol` can be useful for more options.

Comment: If I increase it above 100 % it gets even more distorted

Comment: @SuiciDoga ~ that was to be expected given you mentioned distortion at even lower levels. Is this problem always the same no matter the sound origin? For example is it the same for local files of different formats, youtube and other online sound, etc?

Comment: Everything except Minecraft music is distorted for basses.

Comment: This is not an answer , sound above 100 is very distorted.

Comment: @SurajJain - On my system it's not distorted. - As far as answers go, the above is the only one, and up to the OP to decide.